# Overriding __getattr__ method for one instance of a class?

Tags: python, getattr

I'm working on a project right now that deals with functions in an abstract mathematical sense. Without boring the reader with the details, I'll say that I had the following structure in an earlier version:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.sub_unit = Foo(a, not b)
```

Of course, that's not quite the change I'm making to the arguments to `Foo`, but suffice to say, it is necessary that this property, if accessed repeatedly, result in an indefinitely long chain of `Foo` objects. Obviously, this results in an infinite recursion when one instantiates `Foo`. I solved this in the earlier version by removing the last line of `init` and adding the following to the `Foo` class:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr: str):
    if attr == 'sub_unit':
        return Foo(self.a, not self.b)
    else:
        return super().__getattr__(attr)
```

This worked quite well, as I could calculate the next object in the chain as needed.

In going over the code, though, I realize that for other reasons, I need an *instance* of `Bar`, not a sub-class of it. To see if I could override the `getattr` for a single instance, I tried the following:

```
>>> foo = Bar(a=1, b=2) # sub_unit doesn't get set here.
>>> foo.__getattr__ = lambda attr: 'foo'
>>> foo.a
1
>>> foo.__getattr__('a')
'foo'
```

What is happening here that I don't understand? Why isn't `foo.a` calling `foo.__getattr__('a')`?

Is there a good way to overwrite `__getattr__` for a single instance, or is my best bet to re-factor all the code I have that reads `sub_unit` and friends to call those as functions, to handle this special case?

Comment: See link in other comment - the reason you can't override it is because `__getattr__` is a special method

Comment: Also `__getattr__` is only invoked for *missing* attributes, i.e. those that aren't found the normal way. If you want to intercept access to *all* attributes, implement `__getattribute__`.

Comment: I wasn't fully aware of that subtlety with special methods, and that does seem to be the problem here. In response to your comment, jonrsharpe, I also tried to overwrite `__getattribute__` (though I neglected to mention so, my bad), to no effect. Also, if it's for missing arguments, why does it work in the class-based situation? In `init`, I set `sub_unit = None`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `sub_unit` to be a `property`. Which returns `return Foo(self.a, not self.b)` when accessed.

Comment: @DanD. Properties look promising initially, but I can only seem to get them to work by including them in a class definition. Is there a good way to apply one to a single instance?

Answer (score 1):

When you lookup the attribute `a` with foo.a, python looks it up in the instance's property dictionary. When it is not found, the `__getattr__` method will then be called.

On the contrary, if `a` exists in the instance, `__getattr__` will not be called.